# Why is my date comparison function throwing errors?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an if statement that will compare the input date with the system date.

```
$Date > date('m/d/Y')
```

The problem is that when I input `12/16/2012` it will throw an error that the date is greater than the date today. I don’t know what the problem in my if statement is. I have a `try` and `catch` inside that function that will catch any InputException.

Comment: You're comparing strings, not dates

Comment: Try using strtotime when comparing the dates

Comment: `date_diff( date_create($Date), time());`

Answer (score 0):

Comparing strings will not give you the desired output. You could use `strtotime` to compare the dates like this:
`strtotime($date) > date('m/d/Y',time())`

Comment: You are comparing numbers (`strtotime()`) with strings (`date()`).

Answer (score 0):

```
strtotime($date) > strtotime(date('m/d/Y'));
```

Comment: Why format the current time using `date()` then parse the formatted string using `strtotime()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to parse the value you store in `$Date` to get a timestamp (i.e. the number of seconds passes since Jan 1, 1970). Then you compare it against the current timestamp, retrieved using the function [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

```
if (strototime($Date) > time()) {
    echo($Date.' is in the future.');
} else {
    echo($Date.' is in the past.');
}
```